# Lucene indexes not updating on CD

Tags: indexing, scaling, content-delivery

We have an issue in our UAT environment where the `sitecore_web_index` Lucene index is not getting updated on a content delivery server when content is published.

I found [this solution on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692932/sitecore-lucene-content-delivery-server-index-not-updating-on-publish) which works, but **I don't want to have to change the instance name** of the application to fix the issue. It must be tied to some information in the Sitecore databases that can be reset to bring the indexing functionality back.

Does anyone know what needs to be reset to allow a CD server to resume indexing web database content properly?

Some additional context:

- CM and CD share a single `core` database
- CD `sitecore_web_index` is set up to use `onPublishAsync` strategy
- Renaming the `InstanceName` fixes the issue

Some things I've tried with no success:

- Clearing the `core` database's `Properties` table's entries with the instance name in them
- Clearing the `EventQueue`, `History`, and `PublishQueue` tables on the `core` and `web` databases

Comment: Do you have this strategy added in config. <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
  <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/remoteRebuild" />
</strategies>

Comment: And you have EnableEventQueues set to true?  <setting name="EnableEventQueues" value="true"/>

Comment: Yep. Everything works if I change the InstanceName, so I know it's not a configuration issue.

Comment: @DanSinclair The issue is because of the Scalability settings. You'll need to update the instance name so that Sitecore knows where the publish has been triggered

Comment: You don't have to rename the instance. You can just set `Publishing.PublishingInstance` to the name of your CM server. I usually just set `InstanceName` to `CM` on the CM server and leave the others unnamed.

Comment: I'd also suggest going with Solr instead of Lucene in a multi-server environment. Sitecore doesn't support Lucene in scaled environments and Sitecore does not recommend Lucene in a production environment: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/using-solr,-lucene,-or-azure-search.html

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, changing the InstanceName to something else fixes the issue (as in the linked Q&A from Stack Overflow), but I don't want to do that. I want to fix the actual issue. We already have the `Publishing.PublishingInstance` set properly (again, it's working if I change the CD's instance name).

I also agree that going with Solr is better; we're planning to do that in the near future. But in the meantime, I'd like to diagnose and resolve this issue.

Comment: As @UmarD suggested in his first comment, have you setup your config to have remoteRebuild strategy on the CD instance configuration files ? NOTE that this has to be adjusted on CD instance config files (that means there will be two different settings for CM & CD)

Comment: No, but that doesn't matter. If I change the InstanceName on the CD server, the problem goes away (indexing works as expected), so I know it's not an issue with how the configuration files are set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution requires an AppPool recycle to take effect:

1. Execute the following SQL statement against the `core` database

   ```
   DELETE FROM [Properties] WHERE [Key] LIKE '%_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP%'
   ```
2. Recycle the CD's AppPool

After this, you will want to rebuild the indexes on the CD so that they pick up any changes that were missed while indexing was broken.

Comment: I'm curious if you run this query `SELECT *  FROM [Properties] where [Key] like '%SITECORE_WEB_INDEX%LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP'` if you see two distinct results for your CM Web index and your CD Web index. I bring this up because what you're experiencing could be explained if the autogen'd InstanceName of CM and CD came back the same- in which case setting the InstanceName per server would be the true fix.

Comment: Good question. The InstanceName is different for each server (we just set it to the server name), so they should never overlap.