# Index Update Strategy not Firing on Publish End with Custom Publishing Target and Custom Solr Index

Tags: content-search, solr, publishing, indexing, event-queue

We have a prod set up that has one CM and two CDs. The CD servers serve content from a second web database that we call "live". This database is a clone of web. We use web as a staging environment on the CM server. We have also created a sitecore_live_index and a onPublishEndAsyncLive index update strategy. However, when doing a publish to the "live" publishing target the index update job is not fired. I can see the publish event in both the "live" database event queue table and in the "core" database event queue table. Any suggestions?

Here's the config for the database:

```
<database id="live" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" singleInstance="true" patch:source="_databases.config">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <icon>Images/database_web.png</icon>
    <securityEnabled>true</securityEnabled>
    <dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
        <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
            <disableGroup>publishing</disableGroup>
            <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
                <childLimit>100</childLimit>
                <logStats>false</logStats>
                <template desc="template">{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}</template>
                <template desc="template section">{E269FBB5-3750-427A-9149-7AA950B49301}</template>
                <template desc="template field">{455A3E98-A627-4B40-8035-E683A0331AC7}</template>
                <template desc="language">{F68F13A6-3395-426A-B9A1-FA2DC60D94EB}</template>
                <template desc="device">{B6F7EEB4-E8D7-476F-8936-5ACE6A76F20B}</template>
                <item desc="root">{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}</item>
                <children desc="main sections">{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}</children>
                <cacheSize>100MB</cacheSize>
                <template desc="alias">{54BCFFB7-8F46-4948-AE74-DA5B6B5AFA86}</template>
                <template desc="layout">{3A45A723-64EE-4919-9D41-02FD40FD1466}</template>
                <template desc="Sublayout">{0A98E368-CDB9-4E1E-927C-8E0C24A003FB}</template>
                <template desc="xsl rendering">{F1F1D639-4F54-40C2-8BE0-81266B392CEB}</template>
                <item desc="home">{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}</item>
                <children desc="main items">{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}</children>
                <!--  MVC  -->
                <template desc="Controller rendering">{2A3E91A0-7987-44B5-AB34-35C2D9DE83B9}</template>
                <template desc="Item rendering">{86776923-ECA5-4310-8DC0-AE65FE88D078}</template>
                <template desc="Rendering">{92D4A8C4-5754-4E1A-96A6-095BD193E12B}</template>
                <template desc="Sublayout">{0A98E368-CDB9-4E1E-927C-8E0C24A003FB}</template>
                <template desc="View rendering">{99F8905D-4A87-4EB8-9F8B-A9BEBFB3ADD6}</template>
                <!--  Rules  -->
                <template desc="Action">{F90052A5-B4E6-4E6D-9812-1E1B88A6FCEA}</template>
                <template desc="Condition">{F0D16EEE-3A05-4E43-A082-795A32B873C0}</template>
                <template desc="Conditional Rendering Rule">{550B5CEF-242C-463F-8ED5-983922A39863}</template>
                <template desc="Content Editor Warning Rule">{71A2C881-FBB3-4A23-A187-7FD50A20F924}</template>
                <template desc="Insert Options Rule">{664E5035-EB8C-4BA1-9731-A098FCC9127A}</template>
                <template desc="Rule">{D9BDF22F-6E17-47F3-AB64-49C717BA92DA}</template>
                <template desc="Script">{AB6DD55D-75E3-4A02-9793-7054ED90FCB6}</template>
                <template desc="Element Folder">{54DAE7CD-BFD8-4E69-9679-75F2AE9F9034}</template>
                <template desc="Rule Elements Visibility Rule">{271F5CF1-95C7-474D-9F04-06C6EBB20D8F}</template>
                <template desc="Rules Context Folder">{DDA66314-03F3-4C89-84A9-39DFFB235B06}</template>
                <template desc="Rules Folder">{8EA2CF67-4250-47A2-AECA-4F70FD200DC7}</template>
                <template desc="Tag">{1A9B6300-4652-477C-A4B5-B2A64E86B29F}</template>
                <template desc="Tags Definition">{854BA861-63EA-4A0C-8C7B-541E9A7EC4C1}</template>
                <template desc="Tags Definitions Folder">{96C8E5DD-63C3-496B-A97C-A3E37E1DACBA}</template>
                <template desc="Visibility">{AA91A868-02F2-41D3-8B78-1CAD91B4DCAE}</template>
                <template desc="Validation Result">{29045375-C15F-4E69-B873-75C3F5C1814B}</template>
                <template desc="Validation Rule">{0512BDE9-5696-42C4-8C7D-B349EDA9CEF9}</template>
            </prefetch>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataProviders>
    <PropertyStore ref="PropertyStoreProvider/store[@name='$(id)']"/>
    <remoteEvents.EventQueue>
        <obj ref="eventing/eventQueueProvider/eventQueue[@name='$(id)']"/>
    </remoteEvents.EventQueue>
    <archives hint="raw:AddArchive">
        <archive name="archive"/>
        <archive name="recyclebin"/>
    </archives>
    <cacheSizes hint="setting">
        <data>200MB</data>
        <items>200MB</items>
        <paths>2500KB</paths>
        <itempaths>50MB</itempaths>
        <standardValues>2500KB</standardValues>
    </cacheSizes>
</database>
```

Here is the index:

```
<index id="sitecore_live_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" patch:source="SiteSearch.config">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="core">prod-pmo_live_index</param>
    <param ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" desc="propertyStore" param1="$(id)"/>
    <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration"/>
    <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
        <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsyncLive"/>
    </strategies>
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>live</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore</Root>
        </crawler>
    </locations>
    <enableItemLanguageFallback>false</enableItemLanguageFallback>
    <enableFieldLanguageFallback>false</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
</index>
```

Here is the indexing strategy:

```
<onPublishEndAsyncLive type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.OnPublishEndAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" patch:source="SiteSearch.config">
    <param desc="database">live</param>
    <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>
</onPublishEndAsyncLive>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was resolved by clearing the last updated timestamps from the `core`'s `Properties` table. Does that resolve it for you? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17040/lucene-indexes-not-updating-on-cd

Comment: @DanSinclair as in DELETE FROM [Core].[dbo].[Properties] or am I looking to target something more specific? EDIT: Nevermind, I'l looking at the question that you linked with the following query DELETE
  FROM [Core].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE [Key] LIKE '%_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP%'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution mentioned in Dan Sinclair's comment worked to fix this issue. Thanks Dan!

```
DELETE FROM [Core].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE [Key] LIKE '%_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP%'
```

After running this operation restart your CM/Indexing instance(s).